# How do I adjust the sensitivity of my Bluetooth wireless mouse on Android 11 or Samsung DeX?

Tags: android-11, samsung-dex, samsung-galaxy-s-21

I have an ergonomic wireless Bluetooth mouse from Microsoft that I use when using my Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra in Dex mode. The speed of the mouse cursor is very high by default and I want to make it move slower.

How do I do this in Android and preferably in Dex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out how to configure the mouse cursor sensitivity. In `Settings` go to `Dex Settings > Mouse and Trackpad`. Click on `More Settings` and then adjust the mouse sensitivity with the `pointer speed` adjustment bar.